# Rounding Values

Tags: python

```py
import math 
import random

wallet_amt = random.randrange(1,20)
bank_amt = random.randrange(1,20)
x = wallet_amt + bank_amt

digits = len(str(x))
r = round(x, -(digits-1))
print(f"Wallet amount is {wallet_amt}\nBank amount is {bank_amt}\n\nFinal number is {r}")
```

So this is what im working on right now. A little practice, but can someone please explain to me why this below wouldn't work. Its not something I need help with but I just dont understand why python makes it like that.

```py
import math 
import random

wallet_amt = random.randrange(1,20)
bank_amt = random.randrange(1,20)
x = wallet_amt + bank_amt

r = round(x)
print(f"Wallet amount is {wallet_amt}\nBank amount is {bank_amt}\n\nFinal number is {r}")
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What does "wouldnt work" mean?

Comment: With the one below it it doesnt round it. It just adds them together. Why does python do this

Comment: The second parameter of `round` specifies the number of decimals to round to. By passing a negative number, you go in the opposite direction. For example, `-1` would round to the tens place, `-2` to the hundreds, and so on. That's what the extra code is doing. It is finding the length of your sum and rounding to the most significant digit. If you don't specify any second parameter, as in your first code block, `round` will simply round to the ones place.

Comment: @Tahikato. Your first code. Change this r = round(x, -(digits-1)) to r = round(x, +(digits-1))

Comment: @toyotaSupra Changing that will make it like the second code. If your adding the + it adds the 2 values together which I dont want. I want to round them which i did